# Using AdsOpenObject lock user

Tags: windows, active-directory

We have developed a web program for one of our customers, where we use the company’s AD to validate the user. We use function AdsOpenObject('WinNT://... and this work fine, whoever one fail use of wrong password, and the user is disabled, and need to be reactivated. The AD is set up to use 5 fail login before disabling, and their mail system is working accordingly.

Any ide where to look for or any idea of using another method to validate a user against an AD. We use Delphi but other solution is welcome.